# 802.11ax and non 802.11ax AP on the same channel

Tags: ieee-802.11, ieee-802.1ax

What issues can cause 802.11ax AP that work on the same 2.4GHz channel with, for example, 802.11n AP with different BSSID? Is it worse than two 802.11n APs on the same channel with different BSSID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two APs on the same channel will always cause co-channel interference, no matter if both are 802.11n/802.11ac or a mix of any protocols.

The only exception would be if all APs were coordinated together and had the same BSSID in a single channel architecture mode. In this situation, co-channel interference can still occur, but it is designed to minimize its effects.

Comment: Yes, I know that two APs will suffer from CCI, but at least two 802.11n APs on the same channel will "see" each other and there will be no frame collisions. Is it possible that 802.11n AP will not see 802.11ax AP and 802.11n AP will send data to the media while 802.11ax AP sending its data, thus leading to the collisions?

Comment: Having nearby APs on the same channel with different protocols should be no different then nearby APs on the same channel with the same protocol as CSMA/CA is designed to provide backwards compatibility with all 802.11 protocols.